# Intel RealSense depth camera on Ubuntu Arm

Tags: ros, realsense, camera, 3dcamera, intel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Im going to develop some package with the [Intel RealSense depth camera](http://click.intel.com/intelrrealsensetm-developer-kit-featuring-sr300.html), but before i get that hardware, i wanna know if its possible to use it on the Ubuntu Arm version of ROS.
Thank you so much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228095/intel-realsense-depth-camera-on-ubuntu-arm/) by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on odroid xu4, with sr300 intel camera!
I could use F200 before. But there is no more F200. SR300 is only available now. I am using now SR300 on ODROID XU4 using modified version of librealsene for ARM processor: [librealsense](https://github.com/Maghoumi/librealsense) , and modified ros package for SR300: [realsense](https://github.com/ZahraBoroujeni/realsense). I also patched the linux kernel 14.04 for using  V4L2 backend. The only problem that I have now I should run the node twice to work correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2016-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vijayenthiran](https://answers.ros.org/users/27248/vijayenthiran/) on 2016-06-22**:
I am planning to buy SR300 for Odroid XU4. Is it advisable or should I buy F200?
Are you using [librealsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues) ?